# Read XML parent and child tag value from log file if child tag value condition match in Python

Tags: python, xml, dataframe

I have a log file in which XML and text data is there. I want to read the XML with below conditions and read some values in data frame format.

- Want to read only the set in which `<NEW_DATA>` tag is there inside `<DATA>` tag, ignore all other.
- Then filter only those sets where `ItemState = 'ACTIVE'` and `ItemDisplayState = 'ACTIVE'`.
- Also, create some field from `<Transactions>` tag like first `TransactionID` will be `Main_ItemID` always, second `TransactionID` will be `Second_ItemID`

  - If next `'TransactionType' = 'POINT'` then next 4th & 5th `TransactionID` will be in one column (`Third_ItemID`) until next `'TransactionType' = 'POINT'`.
    Snippet of log file to be parsed:

```
2023-01-29 18:00:01,091 - SENT: <AutomationMessage xmlns:xsi="2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="">
 <Header>
  <SequenceNumber>146</SequenceNumber>
  <Timestamp>1674986401</Timestamp>
  <PVersion>500</PVersion>
  <DeskName>DISPLAY-A</DeskName>
 </Header>
 <Data>
  <AT_INFO xmlns:xsi="2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <MessageID>AT_INFO</MessageID>
   <MessageTime>1674986401</MessageTime>
  </AT_INFO>
 </Data>
 <AB33>1194238753</AB33>
</AutomationMessage>

2023-01-29 18:07:05,411 - SENT: <AutomationMessage xmlns:xsi="2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="">
 <Header>
  <Timestamp>1674986825</Timestamp>
  <DeskName>DISPLAY-A</DeskName>
 </Header>
 <Data>
  <NEW_DATA xmlns:xsi="2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <MessageID>NEW_DATA</MessageID>
   <Action>UPDATE</Action>
   <Data>
    <DeliveryID mi_key="DELIVERY_ID" read_only="true">AB011027 - 1015</DeliveryID>
    <ItemName mi_key="ITEM_NAME" read_only="true">XYZ200</ItemName>
    <ItemID mi_key="ID_HAL">1015</ItemID>
    <Transactions mi_key="TRANSACTION_LIST" read_only="true">
     <Transaction>
      <TransactionPosition mi_key="TRANSACTION_POSITION">1</TransactionPosition>
      <TransactionType mi_key="TRANSACTION_TYPE">ONLINE</TransactionType>
      <TransactionID mi_key="TRANSACTION_ID">1015</TransactionID>
     </Transaction>
     <Transaction>
      <TransactionPosition mi_key="TRANSACTION_POSITION">2</TransactionPosition>
      <TransactionType mi_key="TRANSACTION_TYPE">ONLINE</TransactionType>
      <TransactionID mi_key="TRANSACTION_ID">1005</TransactionID>
     </Transaction>
    </Transactions>
    <NumberOfPackages mi_key="ONLINE_COUNT" read_only="true">3</NumberOfPackages>
    <PointIDA mi_key="POINT_ID_A" read_only="true">23</PointIDA>
    <PointIDB mi_key="POINT_ID_B" read_only="true">19</PointIDB>
    <DeliveryDirection mi_key="DIRECTION_DELIVERY" read_only="true">SOUTH</DeliveryDirection>
    <StartLocation mi_key="LOCATION_START" read_only="true">
     <Station>ABC</Station>
     <Road>
      <Kilometerage>12484</Kilometerage>
     </Road>
    </StartLocation>
    <ItemState mi_key="ITEM_STATE" read_only="true">ACTIVE</ItemState>
    <ItemDisplayState mi_key="ITEM_DISPLAY_STATE">STARTING</ItemDisplayState>
   </Data>
  </NEW_DATA>
 </Data>
</AutomationMessage>

2023-01-29 18:07:05,415 - SENT: <AutomationMessage xmlns:xsi="2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="">
 <Header>
  <Timestamp>1674986825</Timestamp>
  <DeskName>DISPLAY-B</DeskName>
 </Header>
 <Data>
  <NEW_DATA xmlns:xsi="2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <MessageID>NEW_DATA</MessageID>
   <Action>UPDATE</Action>
   <Data>
    <DeliveryID mi_key="DELIVERY_ID" read_only="true">AB011027 - 1015</DeliveryID>
    <ItemName mi_key="ITEM_NAME" read_only="true">XYZ200</ItemName>
    <ItemID mi_key="ID_HAL">1015</ItemID>
    <Transactions mi_key="TRANSACTION_LIST" read_only="true">
     <Transaction>
      <TransactionPosition mi_key="TRANSACTION_POSITION">1</TransactionPosition>
      <TransactionType mi_key="TRANSACTION_TYPE">ONLINE</TransactionType>
      <TransactionID mi_key="TRANSACTION_ID">1015</TransactionID>
      <TransactionDisplay mi_key="DISPLAY_ONLINE">SHORT</TransactionDisplay>
     </Transaction>
     <Transaction>
      <TransactionPosition mi_key="TRANSACTION_POSITION">2</TransactionPosition>
      <TransactionType mi_key="TRANSACTION_TYPE">ONLINE</TransactionType>
      <TransactionID mi_key="TRANSACTION_ID">1005</TransactionID>
      <TransactionDisplay mi_key="DISPLAY_ONLINE">LONG</TransactionDisplay>
     </Transaction>
     <Transaction>
      <TransactionPosition mi_key="TRANSACTION_POSITION">3</TransactionPosition>
      <TransactionType mi_key="TRANSACTION_TYPE">POINT</TransactionType>
      <TransactionID mi_key="TRANSACTION_ID">23</TransactionID>
     </Transaction>
     <Transaction>
      <TransactionPosition mi_key="TRANSACTION_POSITION">4</TransactionPosition>
      <TransactionType mi_key="TRANSACTION_TYPE">ONLINE</TransactionType>
      <TransactionID mi_key="TRANSACTION_ID">1013</TransactionID>
      <TransactionDisplay mi_key="DISPLAY_ONLINE">SHORT</TransactionDisplay>
     </Transaction>
     <Transaction>
      <TransactionPosition mi_key="TRANSACTION_POSITION">5</TransactionPosition>
      <TransactionType mi_key="TRANSACTION_TYPE">ONLINE</TransactionType>
      <TransactionID mi_key="TRANSACTION_ID">1019</TransactionID>
      <TransactionDisplay mi_key="DISPLAY_ONLINE">SHORT</TransactionDisplay>
     </Transaction>
     <Transaction>
      <TransactionPosition mi_key="TRANSACTION_POSITION">6</TransactionPosition>
      <TransactionType mi_key="TRANSACTION_TYPE">POINT</TransactionType>
      <TransactionID mi_key="TRANSACTION_ID">19</TransactionID>
     </Transaction>
    </Transactions>
    <NumberOfPackages mi_key="ONLINE_COUNT" read_only="true">3</NumberOfPackages>
    <NumberOfItems mi_key="ITEM_COUNT" read_only="true">240</NumberOfItems>
    <PointIDA mi_key="POINT_ID_A" read_only="true">23</PointIDA>
    <PointIDB mi_key="POINT_ID_B" read_only="true">19</PointIDB>
    <DeliveryDirection mi_key="DIRECTION_DELIVERY" read_only="true">SOUTH</DeliveryDirection>
    <StartLocation mi_key="LOCATION_START" read_only="true">
     <Station>ABC</Station>
     <Line>T3</Line>
     <Road>
      <Kilometerage>12484</Kilometerage>
     </Road>
    </StartLocation>
    <ItemState mi_key="ITEM_STATE" read_only="true">ACTIVE</ItemState>
    <ItemDisplayState mi_key="ITEM_DISPLAY_STATE">ACTIVE</ItemDisplayState>
   </Data>
  </NEW_DATA>
 </Data>
</AutomationMessage>

2023-01-29 18:07:25,908 - SENT: <AutomationMessage xmlns:xsi="2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="">
 <Header>
  <Timestamp>1674986845</Timestamp>
  <DeskName>DISPLAY-A</DeskName>
 </Header>
 <Data>
  <NEW_DATA xmlns:xsi="2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <MessageID>NEW_DATA</MessageID>
   <Action>UPDATE</Action>
   <Data>
    <DeliveryID mi_key="DELIVERY_ID" read_only="true">AB011028 - 1011</DeliveryID>
    <ItemName mi_key="ITEM_NAME" read_only="true">XYZ333</ItemName>
    <ItemID mi_key="ID_HAL">1011</ItemID>
    <Transactions mi_key="TRANSACTION_LIST" read_only="true">
     <Transaction>
      <TransactionPosition mi_key="TRANSACTION_POSITION">1</TransactionPosition>
      <TransactionType mi_key="TRANSACTION_TYPE">ONLINE</TransactionType>
      <TransactionID mi_key="TRANSACTION_ID">1011</TransactionID>
      <TransactionDisplay mi_key="DISPLAY_ONLINE">SHORT</TransactionDisplay>
     </Transaction>
     <Transaction>
      <TransactionPosition mi_key="TRANSACTION_POSITION">2</TransactionPosition>
      <TransactionType mi_key="TRANSACTION_TYPE">ONLINE</TransactionType>
      <TransactionID mi_key="TRANSACTION_ID">1097</TransactionID>
      <TransactionDisplay mi_key="DISPLAY_ONLINE">LONG</TransactionDisplay>
     </Transaction>
     <Transaction>
      <TransactionPosition mi_key="TRANSACTION_POSITION">3</TransactionPosition>
      <TransactionType mi_key="TRANSACTION_TYPE">POINT</TransactionType>
      <TransactionID mi_key="TRANSACTION_ID">23</TransactionID>
     </Transaction>
     <Transaction>
      <TransactionPosition mi_key="TRANSACTION_POSITION">4</TransactionPosition>
      <TransactionType mi_key="TRANSACTION_TYPE">ONLINE</TransactionType>
      <TransactionID mi_key="TRANSACTION_ID">1877</TransactionID>
      <TransactionDisplay mi_key="DISPLAY_ONLINE">SHORT</TransactionDisplay>
     </Transaction>
     <Transaction>
      <TransactionPosition mi_key="TRANSACTION_POSITION">5</TransactionPosition>
      <TransactionType mi_key="TRANSACTION_TYPE">POINT</TransactionType>
      <TransactionID mi_key="TRANSACTION_ID">19</TransactionID>
     </Transaction>
    </Transactions>
    <NumberOfPackages mi_key="ONLINE_COUNT" read_only="true">3</NumberOfPackages>
    <PointIDA mi_key="POINT_ID_A" read_only="true">23</PointIDA>
    <PointIDB mi_key="POINT_ID_B" read_only="true">19</PointIDB>
    <DeliveryDirection mi_key="DIRECTION_DELIVERY" read_only="true">NORTH</DeliveryDirection>
    <StartLocation mi_key="LOCATION_START" read_only="true">
     <Station>ABC</Station>
     <Road>
      <Kilometerage>13555</Kilometerage>
     </Road>
    </StartLocation>
    <ItemState mi_key="ITEM_STATE" read_only="true">ACTIVE</ItemState>
    <ItemDisplayState mi_key="ITEM_DISPLAY_STATE">ACTIVE</ItemDisplayState>
   </Data>
  </NEW_DATA>
 </Data>
 <AB33>1507126111</AB33>
</AutomationMessage>

2023-01-29 18:30:59,731 - SENT: <AutomationMessage xmlns:xsi="2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="">
 <Header>
  <Timestamp>1674988259</Timestamp>
  <DeskName>DISPLAY-A</DeskName>
 </Header>
 <Data>
  <AT_ITEM_SCHEDULES xmlns:xsi="2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <MessageID>AT_ITEM_SCHEDULES</MessageID>
   <ItemData>
     <Component>ITEM_DULE</Component>
     <Identifier></Identifier>
     <ItemDataComponent>
     <ComponentData>
      <ItemData>
       <DeliveryID mi_key="DELIVERY_ID" read_only="true">AB011027 - 1015</DeliveryID>
       <ItemName mi_key="ITEM_NAME" read_only="true">XYZ200</ItemName>
       <ItemID mi_key="ID_HAL">1015</ItemID>
       <Transactions mi_key="TRANSACTION_LIST" read_only="true">
        <Transaction>
         <TransactionPosition mi_key="TRANSACTION_POSITION">1</TransactionPosition>
         <TransactionType mi_key="TRANSACTION_TYPE">ONLINE</TransactionType>
         <TransactionID mi_key="TRANSACTION_ID">1015</TransactionID>
         <TransactionDisplay mi_key="DISPLAY_ONLINE">SHORT</TransactionDisplay>
        </Transaction>
       </Transactions>
       <DeliveryDirection mi_key="DIRECTION_DELIVERY" read_only="true">SOUTH</DeliveryDirection>
       <StartLocation mi_key="LOCATION_START" read_only="true">
        <Station>ABC</Station>
        <Line>_T3</Line>
        <Road>
         <RoadID>93</RoadID>
         <RoadName>93</RoadName>
         <Kilometerage>12484</Kilometerage>
        </Road>
       </StartLocation>
       <Mode mi_key="ITEM_MODE" read_only="true">CBS</Mode>
       <ItemState mi_key="ITEM_STATE" read_only="true">ACTIVE</ItemState>
       <ItemDisplayState mi_key="ITEM_DISPLAY_STATE">ACTIVE</ItemDisplayState>
      </ItemData>
     </ComponentData>
    </ItemDataComponent>
   </ItemData>
  </AT_ITEM_SCHEDULES>
 </Data>
</AutomationMessage>
2023-01-29 18:30:45,110 - SENT: <AutomationMessage xmlns:xsi="/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="">
 <Header>
  <Timestamp>66666666</Timestamp>
  <DeskName>ROC-AMMI-Z</DeskName>
 </Header>
 <Data>
  <NEW_DATA xmlns:xsi="/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <MessageID>AUT_TRAIN_DATA</MessageID>
   <Action>UPDATE</Action>
   <Data>
    <DeliveryID mi_key="DELIVERY_ID">RH_1032_B - 1040</DeliveryID>
    <ItemName mi_key="ITEM_NAME">XYZ1040</ItemName>
    <ItemID mi_key="ID_HAL">1040</ItemID>
    <Transactions mi_key="TRANSACTION_LIST">
     <Transaction>
      <TransactionPosition mi_key="TRANSACTION_POSITION">1</TransactionPosition>
      <TransactionType mi_key="TRANSACTION_TYPE">ONLINE</TransactionType>
      <TransactionID mi_key="TRANSACTION_ID">1040</TransactionID>
      <TransactionDisplay mi_key="DISPLAY_ONLINE">SHORT_HOOD</TransactionDisplay>
     </Transaction>
     <Transaction>
      <TransactionPosition mi_key="TRANSACTION_POSITION">2</TransactionPosition>
      <TransactionType mi_key="TRANSACTION_TYPE">ONLINE</TransactionType>
      <TransactionID mi_key="TRANSACTION_ID">1039</TransactionID>
      <TransactionDisplay mi_key="DISPLAY_ONLINE">LONG_HOOD</TransactionDisplay>
     </Transaction>
    </Transactions>
    <NumberOfPackages mi_key="ONLINE_COUNT">2</NumberOfPackages>
    <PointIDA mi_key="RAKE_ID_A">15</PointIDA>
    <DeliveryDirection mi_key="DIRECTION_DELIVERY">NORTH</DeliveryDirection>
    <StartLocation mi_key="LOCATION_START" read_only="true">
     <Station>ABC</Station>
     <Road>
      <Kilometerage>99999</Kilometerage>
     </Road>
    </StartLocation>
    <ItemState mi_key="ITEM_STATE">ACTIVE</ItemState>
    <ItemDisplayState mi_key="ITEM_DISPLAY_STATE">ACTIVE</ItemDisplayState>
   </Data>
  </NEW_DATA>
 </Data>
 <AB33>3336487589</AB33>
</AutomationMessage>
```

Output I am looking for:

```
Timestamp         DeliveryID       Main_ItemID     Second_ItemID    Third_ItemID    ItemName      Kilometerage
1674986825      AB011027 - 1015       1015             1005           1013,1019      XYZ200         12484
1674986845      AB011028 - 1011       1011             1097             1877         XYZ333         13555
66666666        RH_1032_B - 1040      1040             1039                          XYZ1040        99999
```

I was trying to write a logic (1st & 2nd condition done) but not sure how to read the tag values with 3rd conditions:

```
with open('ITEM.xml', 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()
s = re.sub(r'<\?xml.*?>', '', ''.join(re.findall(r'<.*>', s)))
s = '<root>'+s+'</root>'
root = ET.fromstring(s)
for items_data in root.findall("./AutomationMessage/Data/NEW_DATA/Data/[ItemState='ACTIVE'][ItemDisplayState='ACTIVE']"):
# Logic to read the tag values with above 3rd condition
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a fairly complex undertaking and this answer won't cover all its aspects. I'll try to concentrate on extracting the data; you'll have to figure out the rest. I'll try to explain most of what's going on, but this won't be a substitute for actually getting familiar with it yourself.

First, you'll have to split your file into separate, **well-formed** xml sub-files. In your question you have 5 such files, separated by text like `2023-01-29 18:00:01,091 - SENT:` . Note that the last one seems not to be well formed, so you'll have to fix that.

Once you do that, you will have to parse each file with an xml parser. I personally prefer lxml, so that's what I use here. Using lxml and xpath, you extract the data and send it to a pandas dataframe.

Let's say that two of your 5 xml files are named `file1` and `file2`:

```
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree

#get your file list
c_docs = [file1, file2]

#structure your dataframe
cols = ["Timestamp", "DeliveryID", "Main_ItemID","Second_ItemID","Third_ItemID","ItemName","Kilometerage"]
rows = []

for c_doc in c_docs:
    #parse the file
    doc = etree.XML(c_doc)
    #using xpath, check if the file meets your conditions
    data = doc.xpath('//Data[.//NEW_DATA[.//ItemDisplayState/text()="ACTIVE"][.//ItemState/text()="ACTIVE"]]')
    if data:
        #collect it into a row
        row = []
        ts = data[0].xpath('..//Header/Timestamp/text()')[0]
        di = data[0].xpath('//DeliveryID/text()')[0]
        #the next one is a little complicated to explain here; just read up 
        #on xpath axes
        #EDIT
        #OLD expression
        #abc = data[0].xpath('//TransactionID[../following-sibling::Transaction/TransactionType="POINT"][not(preceding-sibling::TransactionType[1]="POINT")]/text()')
        #replace with new expression
        abc = data[0].xpath('//TransactionID[not(preceding-sibling::TransactionType[1]="POINT")]/text()')
        kil = data[0].xpath('//Kilometerage/text()')[0]
        #note that you extend the row, not append to it
        row.extend([ts,di,abc[0],abc[1],",".join(abc[2:]),iname,kil])
        #append to the dataframe rows
        rows.append(row)
#now it's time to form the dataframe
pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=cols)
```

Output for the two subfiles I used:

```
Timestamp   DeliveryID  Main_ItemID     Second_ItemID   Third_ItemID    ItemName    Kilometerage
0   1674986825  AB011027 - 1015     1015    1005    1013,1019   XYZ333  12484
1   1674986845  AB011028 - 1011     1011    1097    1877    XYZ333  13555
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Jack..I have changed few things after that it's working fine with almost all the scenario's. But the 'abc' field is not reading the 'TransactionID' value if <Transactions> section doesn't have 'TransactionType' = 'POINT' at last. (added the sample in above xml at the last)

Comment: Sorry I missed that scenario earlier. I found this when started working with actual data files.

Comment: @RKIDEV Sorry for the delay; didn't see this before. See edit. It works with the 2 sample files I used before plus your new scenario.

Comment: @Jack.thank you for the answer. It's working as expected. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified few code as @Jack suggested.
Instead of splitting the original file into multiple files I am iterating each XML doc. The output is fine but in third row 'Second_ItemID' is missing in few cases because the 'abc' variable logic is not able to read the 'ID' as TransactionType='POINT' tag is not there after that. Still looking for the solution.

```
with open(unzip_file_name, 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()
    s = re.sub(r'<\?xml.*?>', '', ''.join(re.findall(r'<.*>', s)))
    s = '<root>'+s+'</root>'    
cols = ["Timestamp", "DeliveryID", "Main_ItemID","Second_ItemID","Third_ItemID","ItemName","Kilometerage"]
rows = []
doc = etree.XML(s)
data = doc.xpath('//Data[.//NEW_DATA[.//ItemDisplayState/text()="ACTIVE"][.//ItemState/text()="ACTIVE"]]')
for i in xrange(len(data)):
    row = []
    ts = data[i].xpath('..//Header/Timestamp/text()')[0]
    lead_id = data[i].xpath('..//ItemID/text()')[0]
    di = data[i].xpath('.//DeliveryID/text()')[0]
    iname = data[i].xpath('.//ItemName/text()')[0]
    abc = data[i].xpath('.//TransactionID[../following-sibling::Transaction/TransactionType="POINT"][not(preceding-sibling::TransactionType[1]="POINT")]/text()')
    kil = data[i].xpath('.//Kilometerage/text()')[0]
    if(len(abc) > 1):
        row.extend([ts,di,lead_id,abc[1],",".join(abc[2:]),iname,kil])
    else:
        row.extend([ts,di,lead_id,"",",".join(abc[2:]),iname,kil])
    rows.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=cols)
```

Output -

```
Timestamp         DeliveryID       Main_ItemID     Second_ItemID    Third_ItemID    ItemName      Kilometerage
1674986825      AB011027 - 1015       1015             1005           1013,1019      XYZ200         12484
1674986845      AB011028 - 1011       1011             1097             1877         XYZ333         13555
66666666        RH_1032_B - 1040      1040                                           XYZ1040        99999
```